# Displaying 3 hex bytes sent to serial port on an OLED display

Tags: arduino-uno

I am new to Arduino and I'm trying my first Pro Mini. I was able to find OLED display code from github that runs perfectly. My problem is trying to show 3 hex bytes sent by a remote control decoder module on the display.

The code will run under serial monitor with `serial.print("I Received");` and `serial.println(incomingByte, HEX);`.

I want to receive this code on the serial port and display it on the OLED screen.

Any help is welcome.

I attached my code any help will be appreciated.

```
int incomingByte = 0
void setup() (
  Serial.begin(9600)
)

void loop() (
  if (serial.available() > 0) (
    incomingByte = Serial.read();
    u8g.drawStr(10, 37" I Received"); //glcd text position
    u8g.setPrintPos(10,42);
    u8g.print(incomingByte, HEX);
  )
)
```

Comment: This code can't work. You're missing semi-colons, a comma, and replaced {} with (). Good luck with that... You need to fix your code first.

Comment: You have to post a complete working example of your code. Your code doesn't even compile.

Comment: I fixed all the errors and the code runs fine, thanks for suggestions and ideas. The u8g draw functions would not run in the loop function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you know the difference and significance between {} and () and the fact that the code you pasted in had a few syntax issues.

Below is a copy which should compile (I haven't tried it) I added a check to see if `Serial.read()` returned data, but otherwise its what you had.

```
int incomingByte = 0;
void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
    if (Serial.available() > 0) 
    {
        incomingByte = Serial.read();
        if (incommingByte != -1)
        {
            u8g.drawStr(10, 37, " I Received"); //glcd text position
            u8g.setPrintPos(10, 42);
            u8g.print(incomingByte, HEX);
        }
    }
}
```

You've not actually said if the code works or not.  Please can you try this version and report the results.